# store excel file to download in Save excel file downloads folder in android 11 and 12 in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-dependencies, android-11

I am a Flutter application that creates data from the user into an Excel file and saves the file to the device’s memory to the downloads section. In Android versions less than 11, it works normally, but in Android versions 11 and above, it does not work, and repeating the operation is not allowed.

The file was expected to be saved to the device's downloads folder, but I encountered this problem
Unhandled Exception: FileSystemException: Cannot open file, path = '/storage/emulated/0/Download/myExcel/2023-10-17 10:19:10.539557.csv' (OS Error: Operation not permitted, errno =1

Answer (score 0):

> 10:19:10.539557.csv

The `:` is a not allowed character in file names.